# FinByValue not working within context of a UserControl DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, properties, drop-down-menu

I am pulling my hair out with this one.

I have an Employee dropdownlist usercontrol (uxEmployee) and I have exposed the SelectedValue method as a property(SelectedValue).

Within my page I am trying to either set the value based on my data or add the value to the list if it is not currently on there.

No matter what I do it is adding the Set value to the list. Even when the value is already on the list; it is still adding the value. Basically FindByValue is always returning "Nothing" no matter what I do. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Public Property SelectedValue() As String

    Get
        Return uxEmployee.SelectedValue
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)

        If Not uxEmployee.Items.FindByValue(value) Is Nothing Then
            uxEmployee.SelectedValue = value
        Else
            uxEmployee.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(value, value))
            uxEmployee.AppendDataBoundItems = True
            uxEmployee.DataBind()
        End If

    End Set
End Property

Public WriteOnly Property Department() As String
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _department = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not (IsPostBack) Then
        Dim emp As New Employee()

        With uxEmployee
            If _department <> String.Empty Then
                .DataSource = emp.GetByDept(_department)
            Else
                .DataSource = emp.GetList()
            End If
            .DataTextField = "FullName"
            .DataValueField = "UserName"
            .DataBind()
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

my calling page uses the following in page load.. uxSalesleadv is an instance of uxemployee

```
    Dim objPrj As ServiceProject = New ServiceProject()
        objPrj = objPrj.GetItem(prjID)
        With objPrj
            uxSalesLead.SelectedValue = .SalesLead
            End With
```

Comment: How are you populating uxEmployee.Items initially ?

Comment: my GetList function which returns a dataset from just a reguluar business object class.

Comment: is it possible to use getselectedvalue within the SET property of a dropdownlist usercontrol? can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

The method performs an exact match and is case-sensitive and culture-insensitive.  Have you checked that the values are identical in the debugger?

Comment: Ive attempted to but I get the generic "In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified.." for the items collection of employee. Im at a loss for this. Ive spent a full day working on this and still have no idea why its not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FindByName()`. If it works, then the values are not being set properly when you initially set the data source.

Comment: still does not work. I have tested findbyvalue using the same procedures but with an onpage ddl rather than a usercontrol and it works ok. Its just in the usercontrol that is not working and i dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error and debugging I have figured out the problem.

I was able to get the control to work correctly when i moved my data assignment from the page_load to the pre_render event. This was not ideal though.. I eventually found that the usercontrol was setting the value before the actual databinding was taking place.

I have now moved the logic out of my Set property and now added logic to my controls page_load databinding to check if the previous SET value is in the databind list. If it isnt then it adds the item. This will allow me to use the usercontrol throughout my apps without any additional page code and worrying about item not in list errors.